# Bash - while loop in a file and stop condition

Tags: bash, while-loop

I want to read a specific value from a /proc file, and currently that's done in a 'while read line' loop, as a scheleton:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = *MATCHES STRING* ]]; then
        for ((  i=0 ;  i<=$someVAR-1;  i++ ))
        do
          [if statement to check if the specific line is not equal with 0]
          then [whatever]
        done
    fi
done < "/proc/FILE"
```

With that, I want to further improve the loop so that I can make count of how many times the if statement inside the for loop returns a value above 0.
So the stop conditions should be like:

```
if line matches string then
for loop
do
use a variable to keep count that the conditions has been met 2 times.
```

When that occurs, the loop should stop and show a message.

Comment: An example might help.

Comment: Increment a variable in the `if` statement. After the loop, test the variable, and use `break` to stop the loop.

Comment: is it possible to grep "MATCHES STRING" in the file & store result in line?

Comment: Hi Barmar - testing the new variable value will have to be done outside the while read line loop, so break will not work.

Comment: @user3144292 i think @Barmar give you solution it's vary right to increment `count` variable in `if` (inside for loop `if`) and check that `count` outside in `while` and use `break` to stop. simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = *MATCHES STRING* ]]; then
        count=0
        for ((  i=0 ;  i<=$someVAR-1;  i++ ))
        do
            [if statement to check if the specific line is not equal with 0]
            then count=$((count+1))
            fi
        done
        if [[ $count -ge 2 ]]
        then break
        fi
    fi
done < "/proc/FILE"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar! I moved the if count outside the while loop as in particular I want to have it go through the entire lines and data.
But again, your answer was very helpful!

Comment: Your question says _when that occurs, the loop should stop_. How can you stop the loop if you do the test outside the loop?